# выпадающее меню jquery убрать назад

Tags: jquery, css

делаю выпадающее меню 
по клику на пункт меню #menu-item-87 у подменю меняется display none на block

```
$('#menu-item-87').click(function(){
    $('.sub-menu').css('display', 'block');
    return false;
});
```

Подменю появляется, а как его обратно убрать по клику?

Comment: использовать http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: `$('.sub-menu').slideToggle();` - приятней появление будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте toggle:

```
$('#menu-item-87').click(function(){
    $('.sub-menu').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#menu-item-87').click(function(){
    $('.sub-menu').toggle('display');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-item-87">Показать\Скрыть
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display:none;">
  <li>#1</li>
  <li>#2</li>
  <li>#3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```